# How Can I make the player moves ignoring rotation and gravity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make my player moves, and I know how to do that. The problem comes when I change the gravity and the direction of the player. For example, if I change gravity to the left and rotation to the left (-90 degrees on the player), when I press right arrow the player moves up instead to the right because it moves on the global space and not in the local one.

I've tried changing the Rigidbody2D velocity according to the tag the gravity changer object has. But that's too inefficient. I've also tried with this code:

```
transform.position += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * transform.right;
```

And that worked, the player moved right and left no matter the rotation. The problem was that, as it only changes the position, the player didn't collide and it could go through walls.

I've been looking here and other forum for an answer and I've been trying on my own for a day, and I don't want to be stuck in this for more time.

Comment: it sounds like its not the gravity that causes it to move up but how you "rotated left", it sounds like you rotate so that if it were a person facing right, you rotated "left" and hes now lying on his back..

Comment: That's true, it's the rotation what causes that

Answer (score 0):

I would trying by using [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html).
From the documentation:

> Moves the rigidbody to the specified position by calculating the
>   appropriate linear velocity required to move the rigidbody to that
>   position during the next physics update. During the move, **neither
>   gravity or linear drag will affect the body**. This causes the object to
>   rapidly move from the existing position, through the world, to the
>   specified position.
>
> Because this feature allows a rigidbody to be moved rapidly to the
>   specified position through the world, **any colliders attached to the
>   rigidbody will react as expected i.e. they will produce collisions
>   and/or triggers**. This also means that if the colliders produce a
>   collision then it will affect the rigidbody movement and potentially
>   stop it from reaching the specified position during the next physics
>   update. If the rigidbody is kinematic then any collisions won't affect
>   the rigidbody itself and will only affect any other dynamic colliders.

So, something like this:

```
rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Comment: I read the documentation and I tried it but it didn't work. I don't know why the player didn't move